# php вычислить логин из email

Tags: php, email

Вопрос в следующем: Хочу сделать быструю регистрацию, тоесть юзер введёт только email. Движку нужен логин, хочу его вычислить из мыла.

Кто-нибудь знает способ как на php можно вычислить все символы до знака @ ?

P.S.
К примеру из admin@mail.ru нужно получить только admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через RegEXP:

```
$string = 'admin@mail.ru';
$pattern = '/@.*?$/';
$replacement = '';
$user_name = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Через explode:

```
$parts = explode("@", "admin@mail.ru ");
$username = $parts[0];
```

Comment: Эмн, ты чего с регуляркой выдумал? Во-первых, это слишком сложно для простой вырезки логина, а во-вторых, это вырежет всё, кроме собаки, вроде бы.

Comment: Да точно тут какой-то фейл, оно домен вроде вернет

Comment: Если припекло, то вот что вырежет домен и собаку: `(@[^@]+$)`.

Comment: Краткость - сестра таланта ))) explode шикарно работает и не нужно писать кучу символов ))))

Comment: Все теперь вроде пофиксил.

Answer (score 5):

Жесть, уж такое можно нагуглить самому.
Так проще всего:

```
$mail = 'root@kali.org';
$login = explode('@', $mail)[0];
```

Comment: Гуглил, не нашёл ничего подходящего. Спасибо за ответы, теперь буду знать про эти функции.

Answer (score 2):

Лол, читайте мануалы чаще http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strstr.php

```
$email  = 'name@example.com';
$user = strstr($email, '@', true); // Начиная с PHP 5.3.0
echo $user; // выводит name
```

Answer (score 0):

Честно сказать, я удивлен, почему никто не предложил самый *быстрый* и *наименее ресурсоемкий* способ вычленения подстроки из строки:

```
$email = 'admin@example.com';
print substr($email, 0, strpos($email, '@'));
```

Если нет гарантии, что символ `@` всегда будет присутствовать в данной строке, используйте условие:

```
$email = 'admin@example.com';

$login = $email;
if (false !== $pos = strpos($email, '@'))
    $login = substr($email, 0, $pos);

print $login;
```

Функции `substr` и `strpos` будут работать намного быстрее и использовать значительно меньше памяти, чем создание массива с помощью `explode` и работа с регулярными выражениями в `preg_match` / `preg_replace`. Особенно это будет заметно на коротких строках (как в адресах электронной почты).

Comment: Чувак, знаешь штуку под названием "Бритва Оккама"?  Следуй ей и не парься. Сказано же что дано мыло, а не случайная строка, из которой нужно вырезать логин мыла. А что до ресурсоёмкости... Где-где, а тут за ней гнаться - стрелять по воробьям из Звезды Смерти :)

Comment: @TheDoctor А смысл использовать `explode('@', $mail)[0]`, если с тем же успехом можно использовать не менее короткий вариант `substr($email, 0, strpos($email, '@'))`, но с большим бенефитом, даже несмотря на то, что он, возможно, тебя не сильно беспокоит. Зачем писать абы что, если можно везде делать как следует?

Comment: Хм, меньше букаф писать? Не спорю, твой вариант быстрее, но существенно ли?

Comment: @TheDoctor Ну мы ж не знаем где в конечном итоге автор (или читающие) будут использовать этот код. А вдруг в цикле на 10000 итераций? Может быть всякое. Всегда неплохо иметь ввиду быстрый вариант.

Comment: Угу, на пять миллионных секунды :)
Нам не дали условий с тысячами итераций, поэтому нужно предположить самое простое. Ведь всё простое - это гениально!

Comment: Вообще то в вопросе указано зачем мне это нужно (в первой части вопроса). Вариант @TheDoctor прекрасно справляется с поставленной задачей.